# What is the type of props in JMeter's world?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I'm writing my test cases in JMeter and I'm at the point when information should be passed between threads. The only thing I don't know is the type of `props`, so I can't use it easily in my Groovy code.

What is the type of props?

My groovy code looks like this:

```
class NiceGroovyClass {

    JMeterVariables vars
    Logger log
    <props.type???> props

    ConfigurationManager(
            Logger log,
            JMeterVariables vars,
            <props.type???> props) {
        this.vars = vars
        this.log = log
        this.props = props
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) shows that it is a java.util.Properties instance

> props
>   (JMeterProperties - class java.util.Properties) - e.g. `props.get("START.HMS");` `props.put("PROP1","1234");`

You could always check the result of `props.getClass().toString()` to validate this

Comment: Honestly, it seemed too simple solution at first sight. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Groovy you can use the following methods to get information on an arbitrary object:

- [dump()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#dump())
- [inspect()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#inspect())

Example output:

[image]

So `props` is basically an instance of [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article to learn more about the most popular [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available from JSR223 test elements